# ruby on rails : how to bring changes on database to model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have update migrate script under db/migrate, and I did a

```
rake db:migrate
```

database script before update

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :firstname
      t.string :lastname      
      t.string :account
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

databse script after update

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :firstname
      t.string :lastname      
      t.string :account
      t.string :address      
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :postcode                        
      t.string :homephone
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

after I dropped the old development.sqlite3 and old schema in schame.rb.
Say I added a few columns, but in the model these columns is missing.

But my model still is

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :firstname,:lastname,:account,
end
```

Is there a easy way I can bring the changes in new migrate script to model ?

Comment: What kind of changes do you mean?

Comment: @eeeeeean  Say I added a few columns, but in the model these columns is missing

Comment: give examples. your question is vague.

Comment: @hyngyn I have updated original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like maybe you did `rails generate migration` which isn't meant to affect your model. I believe after you create your model everything afterward has to be done manually.

If you really want to effect changes to your database and model at the same time, your best bet might be to delete your migrations and model and do a `rails generate scaffold` ([documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)) to create your entire scaffolding from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow for mass assignments of the other attributes, you can just add the keys to attr_accessible

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :firstname,:lastname,:account,:address, :city, :state, :postcode, :homephone
end
```

However, your model still has those attributes (or columns as you call them). You just can't do a mass assignment (like create or update_attributes) without making them attr_accessible first.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problem to add the new columns manually in the model.